# React native: doesn't show useful error stack when crashed

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

When my react-native app crashes in development mode in simulator, it used to show me useful error stack like which line in which file failed. But it started to give me errors like this after a recent upgrade.

Can anyone tell me how to let it show useful error stack messages? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: i dont think this is about the recent upgrade, but there are some cases when RN does not show really helpful error log. In that case what i do is go over that part of code that i most recently wrote and most of the times you find the issue there. And if still that does not help you should think if you had recently added a new library or package from npm,